# Using spring security

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring security in my application for authenticating. I want to fail all logins which happened within a specific time period since session start(e.g 150ms). I can write code to achieve this. I wanted to know if spring security has this functionality built in where I can specify a timeperiod and all login request within that specified time fails.

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such built-in mechanism in spring for this usecase. Your requirement seems not really a common requirement and therefore could not be expected to find something like this in a general programming framework.